# Test cases conflict in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm fairly new to testing in Python and I've come upon some weird behavior which I can't understand.

I have mocked class `MockedClass` and I'm using it in two test classes like this (both classes are in the same file):

First class:

```
class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mocked_object_1 = MockedClass()
```

Second class:

```
class TestClass2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mocked_object_2 = MockedClass()
```

Mocked objects are passed as arguments to tested functions. What happens now is that when these two tests are run separately (in different files), all tests in those classes are successful, but when they are both run in the same file, all test cases in `TestClass2` fail.

I managed to solve this (somehow) by declaring global `temp_mocked_object` and doing this:

```
class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        temp_mocked_object = self.mocked_object_1
        self.mocked_object_1 = MockedClass()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mocked_object_1 = temp_mocked_object
```

But I don't see why would this problem even occur, much less do I understand why this solution worked. What confuses me the most is that second test fails despite different mocked object names.

Mocked class is structured this way:

```
class MockedClass(someScript.OriginalClass):
    def __init__(self):
        # some unimportant objects are initialized here
```

I'm working in older Python version (2.7), but I think that doesn't matter.

So I would greatly appreciate some kind of explanation about what's going on here, since I couldn't find the answer elsewhere.